# Equal horizontal spacing UICollectionView, including insets - UICollectionViewFlowLayout?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm trying to create equal horizontal spacing between two `UICollectionViewCell` and between a `UICollectionViewCell` an the screen border. It should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Slo67.jpg).

I think it is possible to use `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` to adjust the width of every `UICollectionViewCell`, so they have equal spacings regardless of the phone's size. There should always only be 3 cells on each row.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should add constants for all parameters of `UICollectionView` to the controller:

```
let itemsPerRow = 3
let spaceBetweenItems: CGFloat = 20.0
let spaceBetweenLines: CGFloat = 40.0
let itemHeight: CGFloat = 50.0
```

You mentioned that item's width should be adjustable. You can calculate it with this function:

```
var itemWidth: CGFloat {
    return (self.collectionView.frame.width - CGFloat(self.itemsPerRow + 1) * self.spaceBetweenItems) / CGFloat(self.itemsPerRow)
}
```

Of course you need to customise layout of your `UICollectionView` instance:

```
var collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    let result = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    result.itemSize = CGSize(width: self.itemWidth, height: self.itemHeight)
    result.minimumInteritemSpacing = self.spaceBetweenItems
    result.minimumLineSpacing = self.spaceBetweenLines
    result.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: self.spaceBetweenItems, bottom: 0.0, right: self.spaceBetweenItems)
    result.scrollDirection = .vertical
    return result
}
```

And in the function `viewDidLoad` or your controller you should call `setupCollectionView()`. Here is a code of this function:

```
func setupCollectionView() {
    self.collectionView.frame = self.view.frame
    self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = self.collectionViewLayout
}
```

You will see something like this:

[image: UICollectionView]